# Error with loading data without internet connection (Restkit)

Tags: objective-c, restkit

After making the rest call through RKObjectManager,it is not loading the objects when i don't have internet connection. I test with domain.local and my WIFI is Off.

I know that i can implement with "reachabilityObserver" but i don't know how can i make this.

My code :

```
#import "ViewInformationForm.h"
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>

@interface User : NSObject {
    NSNumber*        _user_forfait;
    NSNumber*        _user_client_free;
    NSNumber*        _user_demande_portabilite;
    NSNumber*        _user_mail_confirm;
    NSNumber*        _user_mail_enregistrement_inscrption;
    NSNumber*        _user_mail_depart_expedition;
    NSNumber*        _user_mail_arrivee_expedition;
    NSNumber*        _user_activation;
    NSNumber*        _user_portabilite;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber*        user_forfait;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber*        user_client_free;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber*        user_demande_portabilite;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber*        user_mail_confirm;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber*        user_mail_enregistrement_inscrption;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber*        user_mail_depart_expedition;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber*        user_mail_arrivee_expedition;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber*        user_activation;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber*        user_portabilite;

@end

@implementation User

@synthesize user_forfait = _user_forfait;
@synthesize user_client_free = _user_client_free;
@synthesize user_demande_portabilite = _user_demande_portabilite;
@synthesize user_mail_confirm = _user_mail_confirm;
@synthesize user_mail_enregistrement_inscrption = _user_mail_enregistrement_inscrption;
@synthesize user_mail_depart_expedition = _user_mail_depart_expedition;
@synthesize user_mail_arrivee_expedition = _user_mail_arrivee_expedition;
@synthesize user_activation = _user_activation;
@synthesize user_portabilite = _user_portabilite;

@end


@implementation ViewInformationForm;
@synthesize picker,pickerDate, forfaitNames;
@synthesize forfaitText, TextDateEnregistrement;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)LoadData {


    RKObjectMapping* mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[User class]];
    [mapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:
     @"data.user_forfait", @"user_forfait",
     @"data.user_client_free", @"user_client_free",
     @"data.user_demande_portabilite", @"user_demande_portabilite",
     @"data.user_mail_confirm", @"user_mail_confirm",
     @"data.user_mail_enregistrement_inscrption", @"user_mail_enregistrement_inscrption",
     @"data.user_mail_depart_expedition", @"user_mail_depart_expedition",
     @"data.user_mail_arrivee_expedition", @"user_mail_arrivee_expedition",
     @"data.user_activation", @"user_activation",
     @"data.user_portabilite", @"user_portabilite",
     nil];

    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];


    NSString* urlUID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/user/data?uid=%@",uuid];
    RKObjectLoader *objectLoader = [objectManager objectLoaderWithResourcePath:urlUID delegate:self];
    objectLoader.method = RKRequestMethodGET;
    objectLoader.objectMapping = mapping;
    [objectLoader send];

}


- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray*)objects {
    User* user = [objects objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString* info = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                      @"\n user_forfait : %@ \n"
                      @"user_client_free : %@",[user user_forfait], [user user_client_free]];
    NSLog(@"%@",info);
}

- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    RKLogError(@"Load of RKRequest %@ failed with error: %@", objectLoader, error);                      
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView
{
}
*/


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:gRKCatalogBaseURL];



    [self LoadData];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.forfaitNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                         @"-- Sélectionnez un forfait --", @"Forfait 19,99 €", @"Forfait 15,90 €", @"Forfait 2 €",
                         @"Forfait 0 €", nil];
}
```

Error :

```
2012-01-24 09:59:32.120 Free M. Stats[13438:10703] I restkit:RKLog.m:30 RestKit initialized...
2012-01-24 09:59:32.127 Free M. Stats[13438:10703] I restkit.network.reachability:RKReachabilityObserver.m:369 Network availability has been determined for reachability observer <RKReachabilityObserver: 0x8987300 host=0.0.0.0 isReachabilityDetermined=YES isMonitoringLocalWiFi=652464 reachabilityFlags=-R tc----->
2012-01-24 09:59:32.129 Free M. Stats[13438:10703] E restkit.network:RKRequest.m:464 Failed to send request to http://freemobile-stats.local/user/data?uid=b070b4f0a581cf1a16312b7bbb31353c due to unreachable network. Reachability observer = <RKReachabilityObserver: 0x8987300 host=0.0.0.0 isReachabilityDetermined=YES isMonitoringLocalWiFi=652464 reachabilityFlags=-R tc----->
2012-01-24 09:59:32.130 Free M. Stats[13438:10703] E app:ViewInformationForm.m:102 Load of RKRequest <RKObjectLoader: 0x6e69050> failed with error: Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=2 "The client is unable to contact the resource at http://freemobile-stats.local/user/data?uid=b070b4f0a581cf1a16312b7bbb31353c" UserInfo=0x6c99270 {NSLocalizedDescription=The client is unable to contact the resource at http://freemobile-stats.local/user/data?uid=b070b4f0a581cf1a16312b7bbb31353c}
```

Thank you for your help.
AO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you register for the reachability notifications in RestKit:

```
// Register for changes in network availability
NSNotificationCenter* center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[center addObserver:self selector:@selector(reachabilityDidChange:) name:RKReachabilityDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

And here you catch the notification:

```
- (void)reachabilityDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    RKReachabilityObserver* observer = (RKReachabilityObserver *) [notification object];
    RKReachabilityNetworkStatus status = [observer networkStatus];
    if (RKReachabilityNotReachable == status) {
        RKLogInfo(@"No network access!");
    } else if (RKReachabilityReachableViaWiFi == status) {
        RKLogInfo(@"Online via WiFi!");
    } else if (RKReachabilityReachableViaWWAN == status) {
        RKLogInfo(@"Online via Edge or 3G!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how delete observer because, if i launch a alertview on Didload View, the next time that i come back on the view, there are 2 two.

Comment: This should do it: `NSNotificationCenter* center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[center removeObserver:self name:RKReachabilityDidChangeNotification object:nil];`

Comment: When a place the addObserver on viewDidLoad and removeObserver on viewDidUnload, there is the same problem. Observer is not empty and my alertview is show X more time.

Comment: I don't know what exactly are you trying to achieve, but maybe try adding the observer on *viewWillAppear:* and removing it on *viewDidDisappear*.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even have to register to Restkit reachability notifications system because it is already implemented in the RKRequest method.

So, if no internet connection is detected, your request will fail and this delegate (that you may have already implemented) is called :

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // No internet !
}
```

Beware, this delegate can also be called for others reasons, like when there is an error in the mapping of your data. But for simple cases it should be ok for what you want to do !

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, it won't load data from the Internet if there's no Iternet connection. You may want to try one of the pre-implemented Reachability classes, for example: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Classes_Reachability_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Classes_Reachability_h-DontLinkElementID_5